# How to change the style of an element when clicked in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to change the colour style of a checkbox when clicked on, in react.  It should also toggle back to the old colour when clicked again.

```
function handleClick() {
     DO SOMETHING HERE TOGGLE THE FILL COLOR
  }

  <CheckCircle onClick={handleClick} style={{ fill: colors.orange }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state for this.

Define the state in your component:

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false)
```

The handleClick funtion would look like this:

```
function handleClick() {
    setClicked(!clicked);
}
```

Finally use the `clicked` variable to adjust your style. Maybe something like this:

```
<CheckCircle onClick={handleClick} style={{ fill: clicked ? colors.orange : colors.red }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(true)

function handleOnClick() {
  setIsChecked(prevState => !prevState)
}

return <CheckCircle onClick={handleOnClick} style={{ fill: isChecked ? colors.orange : OTHER_COLOR }} />
```